# jQuery sortable with multiple tbody

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable, tablerow

I have a table with multiple `tbody`. How can I make headers for each `tbody`? Is this how to do it? I use jquery ui sortable. How can I be sure the header of each `tbody` isn't sortable? Right now I'm triggering sortable with
 `$("#sortable > tbody").sortable({});`.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="rowgroup">Col1</th>
            <th>100</th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>20</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>30</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>50</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="rowgroup">Col1</th>
            <th>100</th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>20</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>30</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>50</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interesting structure you've got there.

I assume you want the rows sortable only within their own `<tbody>` respectively, **excluding the row(s) that contain `<th>` elements**.

Luckily, jQuery has `:has()`

```
$("#sortable > tbody").sortable({
    items: 'tr:has(td)'
});
```

or `tr:not(:has(th))`, but seems less efficient (just a guess)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/Bs2jV/

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Also, you can add `connectWith: 'tbody'`, just in case you want the rows `droppable` to any `<tbody>` within your table.

As in:

```
$("#sortable > tbody").sortable({
    items: 'tr:has(td)',
    connectWith: 'tbody'
});
```

Please comment on which result you are after. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Could the structure be different? I've been looking for a way to make subtotals within a table.

Comment: @user2232982 Perhaps multiple `<thead>` elements within the same table? Alternate thead, tbody, thead, tbody...? I'm not sure if it's valid HTML though, if you care about HTML validation.

Comment: You can have as many `tbody` as you want, but only one `thead` and `tfoot`. However, you can give your `tbody` some CSS class and make only some specific ones sortable.

Comment: You can always use `Cancel` options of sortable to get your solution.